# Mouse only responding to every 2nd-4th click?

Tags: windows-10

Very strange. Windows 10 Pro.

Computer that is used only occasionally and no settings changed, suddenly the Windows is only accepting approximately every 3d/4th click. All applications.

Accepting click is erratic, sometimes you get 2 clicks OK in a row, sometimes you have to click 4 times on button/tab/wherever.

Tried to change mouse, didn't help. Same mouse works OK on another computer. Tried to change USB port used.

Anyone experienced this? Any suggestions?

Comment: Any other cursor input device (which accepts clicks) that might be interfering (eg, touchscreen, touchpad/trackpad, trackpoint/pointing stick, etc.)?  If so, try disabling them to see if your mouse clicks become more responsive.  Otherwise, review your system input hooks (with Process Explorer), and uninstall any that you don't need.

Comment: Maybe it is related to drivers? I don't know, try reinstalling mouse driver and see if it helps.

Comment: Is it happening when booting in Safe Mode?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I'll try all of the above.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you can try to confirm what exactly is causing this problem.

1. Remove device from Settings > Device Manager > Mouse & Pointing Devices > Uninstall. Now, plug the mouse again and it should appear in the list. Right click and Update driver. If it was due to drivers, this should resolve it.
2. Connect your mouse to another computer/laptop and open [cps counter](https://cpscounter.info) in your browser. Now click on the screen and see if the counter increases with every click. If yes, that means your mouse is good; if not, its time to get a new mouse.
3. Try the step 1 with another mouse and see if it works. In case this mouse is also behaving the same, try removing any other wireless devices from your computer and check again.